# Need help managing navigators in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm currently implementing a small React Native app, and here is the navigators I'm currently having:

```
    const RootNav=  createStackNavigator(
     {
      Login: LogInScreen,
     },
    );
    const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
     {
      Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
      Calendar: { screen: CalendarScreen },
      Discussion: { screen: DiscussionScreen },
      Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
     },
    );
    export const SwitchNav = createSwitchNavigator(
     {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      Auth: RootNav,
      MainApp: TabNav,
     },
     {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
     },
    );
```

Right now in HomeScreen and CalendarScreen there are several `Card` components which should navigate to another screen named `EventScreen` with the options to go back to the previous screen which should be another `createStackNavigator` I think, but I still need help what's the right way to set up the navigators. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parent `StackNavigator` with `EventScreen` and `TabNav` as its children:

```
const RootNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LogInScreen,
  }
);

const HomeNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    tabNav: TabNav,
    Events: { screen: EventScreen },
  }
);

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Calendar: { screen: CalendarScreen },
    Discussion: { screen: DiscussionScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
  }
);

export const SwitchNav = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Auth: RootNav,
    MainApp: HomeNav,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

If you feel like you'll need a `DrawerNavigation` as well in the future, it is a good idea to take care of it now. [This article](https://medium.com/async-la/react-navigation-stacks-tabs-and-drawers-oh-my-92edd606e4db) may help.